# Attempting to make a program that draws a rectangle based on where the user presses

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a program that displays an image, letting the user click in two places and then drawing a rectangle between those two places. I am trying to use matplotlib patches however everything works returning the coordinates of the places that I click however it doesn't draw a rectangle. I am trying to use patches however nothing happens.

PS They are stored as arrays for later use.

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches

# reads the image from the file location
img_path = 'C:\sheepdata\sheep1.png'
image = cv2.imread(img_path)
height, width, channels = image.shape
axis = plt.gca()
figure = plt.gcf()
plt.imshow(image)

#the function that will draw the rectangle based on the two places that the user clicks (left first, then right)
def click(event):
    X1 = 0
    X2 = 0
    Y1 = 0
    Y2 = 0
    
    x1.clear()
    y1.clear()
    x2.clear()
    y2.clear()
    #if they click left it will run this statement
    if event.button == 1:
        #cords used to check what was the last button the user pressed, makes sure it they dont click left twice
        if len(cords) == 0:
            #stores the data in the according array
            x1.append(event.xdata)
            y1.append(event.ydata)
            X1 = event.xdata
            Y1 = event.ydata
            print(x1[0], y1[0])
            #changes the value of len(cords) so it now expects the user to press the right mouse button
            cords.append(1)
    #checks for right mouse button press
    if event.button == 3:
        #checks what button it should be expecting
        if len(cords) > 0:
            #stores the cooardinates of the second cooardinates
            x2.append(event.xdata)
            y2.append(event.ydata)
            X2 = event.xdata
            Y2 = event.ydata
            print(x2[0], y2[0])

            rect = patches.Rectangle((X1, Y1), X2 - X1, Y2 - Y1, linewidth=1, edgecolor='r',
                                     facecolor='none')
            axis.add_patch(rect)
            cords.clear()


def draw_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    axis.plot(x1[0], y1[0], 'blue')
    axis.plot(x1[0], y2[0], 'blue')
    axis.plot(x2[0], y1[0], 'blue')
    axis.plot(x2[0], y2[0], 'blue')


cords = []
x1 = [1]
y1 = [1]
x2 = [1]
y2 = [1]

cid = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', click)

# shows the image
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `matplotlib` is the best tool to build this out of.

Comment: is it possible in matplotlib, because I don't really have enough time to start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two main issues with your code. The first is that even though you print out the first coordinate after the click, you are overwriting that value when you click for the second coordinate because you have `X1 = 0` and `Y1 = 0` at the beginning of your function. Secondly, you are missing a call to tell matplotlib to redraw the figure, i.e. `figure.canvas.draw()`.

To do what you want, I used global variables to keep track of the clicked coordinates (I don't love global variables but I think they are fine for this application) and only created the rectangle after two clicks have been made. Note: my version uses two left clicks to determine the locations of the points. (I also use slightly different notation to use what is more standard.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np

plt.close("all")

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
x = rng.random(50)
y = rng.random(50)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
rectangle = None
rectangle_coords = []

def on_click(event):
    global rectangle_coords, rectangle
    if event.button is not MouseButton.LEFT:
        return

    # remove the previous rectangle if clicked again
    if len(rectangle_coords) == 2:
        rectangle_coords = []
        rectangle.remove()

    x = event.xdata
    y = event.ydata
    rectangle_coords.append((x, y))

    if len(rectangle_coords) == 1:
        print(rectangle_coords[0])

    # plot the rectangle after two points have been saved
    if len(rectangle_coords) == 2:
        print(rectangle_coords[1])
        width = rectangle_coords[1][0] - rectangle_coords[0][0]
        height = rectangle_coords[1][1] - rectangle_coords[0][1]
        rectangle = Rectangle(rectangle_coords[0], width, height,
                              linewidth=1,
                              edgecolor="r",
                              facecolor="none")
        ax.add_patch(rectangle)

    fig.canvas.draw()

plt.connect("button_press_event", on_click)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks so much man, been at this for the past 3 days and its finally working.  Saved my ass!